# PHP File Upload tmp_name Does Not Exist

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a screenshot with a file input and an ajax request. This is my request code:

```
  var formData= new FormData();
  formData.append('pictureFile', fileInput.files[0]);
  $.ajax({
                       url: 'data/Upload.php',
                       type: 'POST',
                       processData: false,
                       contentType: false,
                       data: formData,
                       success: function (result) {
                           console.log(result);
                       }
                   });
```

My php code:

```
$fileName = $_FILES['pictureFile']['tmp_name'];

echo $fileName;

move_uploaded_file($fileName,"dirname");
```

The upload doesn't seem to be working however, the echo shows me this:

```
/data/sites/web/hostname/tmp/phplywZbl
```

When I check this directory right after making the request, it's empty!

I checked the php.ini file and file uploads are definitely on (max size = 2M, screenshot is 25kb).

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: This seems like a permissions issue. You'll need to check the write / ownership of the folder.

Comment: See [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) to see how to enable output of warning messages that should help with diagnosis

Comment: When you echo something back to the client, the script stops executing. Don't echo until the upload is complete

Comment: The file is non-existent when you check because its just there for the length of that instance, so its only accessible during the POST request. Then it destroys itself.